# Kinect 3D to 2D bias

Tags: c++, kinect, openkinect

I am struggling with the interpretation of kinect depth data.

In order to obtain real world distance from kinect, i used the following formula :

```
  if(i<2047){
        depthToMeterTable[i] = i * -0.0030711016  + 3.3309495161; 
    }
    else{
        depthToMeterTable[i] = 0;
    }
```

This formula gives something pretty good as a distance estimator.

However i do obtain strange output from a 90° wall corner visualisation.

On the following image is two different information. First, the violet lines represent the wall as i SHOULD see it. A 90° corner. The red dots represent the wall seen from the kinect. As you can see, the angle of the two planes is now bigger.

http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/4061/kinectbias.jpg

Do you have any idea where i could correct this bias, and how to do it ?

Thank you for reading,

Al_th

Comment: What SDK are you using?  Official Microsoft Kinect for Windows, or a 3rd party SDK?

Comment: I am developping my soft in c++ using libfreenect (http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: Any joy with the issue ?

Comment: Nope, not for the moment. But I assume the problem is not inherent to the depth to distance calculation. It may be due to a bad implementation of the algorithm I use to reconstruct walls :x

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that conversion formula (also not sure how your depthToMeterTable gets filled - what formula is used there).

There's a built-in function in libfreenect for that though: [freenect_camera_to_world](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/src/registration.c#L318)

Before that utility function was added I used [Matt Fischer's conversion functions](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Kinect.html)(RawDepthToMeters and DepthToWorld).

HTH